# Can you use a Laravel ::get statement with php date() inside to turn day number into a day name?

Tags: laravel, get

Hi I am trying to get Laravel to output a day number as a day name instead by adding php date function into the query thus:

`DeliveryOptions::get((date('l', strtotime('day_of_week')) AS 'day_of_week'), 'delivery_slot_hour_start', 'delivery_slot_hour_end');`

Is this possible?

Comment: If you're using Laravel, then you can use Carbon too. It comes pre-installed with Laravel installations. Which is 100 times easier.

Answer (score 1):

Use carbon library

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

 $date= date from query
 $d    = new DateTime($date);
 $d->format('l');
```